# Deeplink doesn't work on react-native ios when app is already open

Tags: react-native, deep-linking, expo, react-native-firebase

I just detached from `expo` and started integrating `react-native-firebase`.

The most important feature for me is firebase dynamic link.

After following their documentation [here](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.3.x/links/ios), i can open the app with dynamic link, and get the url using `Linking.getInitialURL`,

But when the app is already open, Dynamic link will open the app, but doesn't trigger neither `Linking.getInitialURL` nor `Linking.addEventListener('url', ..`.
Also tried `firebase.link.onLink` but no chance.

I tried also a fresh react native project, integrated with react-native-firebase, ( no expo ), and it works if i use react-native linking functions in AppDelegate.m instead of react-native-firebase recommendations.

So apparently there's something wrong with expokit and liking feature.

How i can get the dynamic link url when the react native app is already open.

Thanks